# Showing the existence of a $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please I need help for this exercise, I am reviewing for my Algebra Exam. Thank you in Advance.

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Let $H$ be a non-trivial characteristic subgroup of $G$. Show that there is a subgroup $Z$ of $G$ of order $p$ such that $Z \subseteq H\cap Z(G)$ and $f(x) = x$ for all $f \in P$ and $x \in Z$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Whatcha stuck on?

Comment: Hi, Please I need any hint to start solving this exercise

Comment: Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Here some hints to get started, I will append a suggestion for a complete solution based on that tipps below. I will denote the neutral element of $G$ with $1$.

Hints:

1. Convince yourself that it is enough to find a single element $1\neq x\in H\cap Z(G)$ which has the property "$f(x)=x$ for all $f\in P$" (given such a $x$, consider an appropriate subgroup $Z\subset\langle x\rangle$)
2. To find a $x$ with this property in $H$, consider the orbits of the natural action of $P$ on $H$ (which exists as $H$ was assumed to be a characteristic subgroup of $G$) - what can you say about their lengths? Why is an orbit (besides that of $1$) of length $1$ desirable and why must there be such an orbit?
3. Use the natural embedding $G/Z(G)\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and the sylow theorems to ensure that this $x$ is in $Z(G)$ as well.

Suggestion for a complete solution:

1. If $x\in H\cap Z(G)$ has the property that $f(x)=x$ for any $f\in P$, then the same is true for any $y\in\langle x\rangle$, as, by definition $y=x^i$ for some $i\in\mathbb N$, so $f(y)=f(x^i)=f(x)^i=x^i=y$. If $1\neq x$, then $\lvert\langle x\rangle\rvert >1$, so $\lvert\langle x\rangle \rvert = p^k$ for some $k>0$ by the Lagrange theorem and because $G$ is a $p$-group. As a cyclic $p$-group, $\langle x\rangle$ has a subgroup $Z$ of order $p$ which has the desired property.
2. $H$ being a characteristic subgroup of $G$ means, by definition, that $f(x)\in H$ for any $x\in H$ and any $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. So we get a well defined group action 
   $$P\times H\rightarrow H,\quad (f,x)\mapsto f(x)$$
   of $P$ on $H$. For every orbit $Px_i$ of this action, we have $\lvert Px_i\rvert = \lvert P\rvert /\lvert P_{x_i}\rvert $ (where $P_{x_i}$ is the isotropy group of $P$ at $x_i$), in particular $\lvert Px_i\rvert $ divides $\lvert P\rvert$, so $\lvert Px_i\rvert = p^j$ for some $j$. Using the class equation, $\lvert H\rvert = \sum_i\lvert Px_i\rvert$ (where the sum reaches over all different orbits) we find, using $P1=\{1\}$, that there must be another orbit $Px$ with $\lvert Px\rvert = 1$. By this choice, $x\in H$ has the property $f(x)=x$ for all $f\in P$.
3. Finally, consider the natural morphism $G\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(G),~ g\mapsto \varphi_g$, with $\varphi_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$. The kernel of this is nothing but $Z(G)$, so $G/Z(G)\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is injective. In particular, considering $G/Z(G)$ as a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, it must be contained in some $p$-Sylow subgroup $S$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. By some Sylow theorem, there is a $h\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ such that $P=h^{-1}Sh$. This means that for any $u\in S$, we know that $h^{-1}uh(x)=x$, i.e. 
   $$u(h(x))=h(x)$$ for any $u\in S$. In particular, $\varphi_g(h(x))=h(x)$ for any $g\in G$, i.e. $h(x)\in Z(G)$. But then $h^{-1}(h(x))=x\in Z(G)$, as we get that for any $a\in G$, we may write $a=h^{-1}(b)$ for $b=h(a)$, in particular 
   $$ax=h^{-1}(b)h^{-1}(h(x))=h^{-1}(bh(x))=h^{-1}(h(x)b)=h^{-1}(h(x))h^{-1}(b)=xa.$$

Kind regards!